# Cannot install bgzip on Red Hat

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum

I'm trying to install bgzip on red hat.

```
sudo yum install bgzip
```

says

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:47 ago on Thu 19 May 2022 12:03:12 PM CDT.
No match for argument: bgzip
Error: Unable to find a match: bgzip
```

Following advice from https://installati.one/centos/7/htslib-tools/ I have also tried `sudo yum install htslib-tools` with a nearly identical response.

I have done with `yum` and `dnf`:

`sudo yum makecache` and then `sudo yum -y install htslib-tools`

but neither of those sequences of commands worked.

I have also tried https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/htslib-tools-1.9-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html and downloaded `htslib-1.9-5.el7.src.rpm` and then try to install via `sudo yum localinstall htslib-1.9-5.el7.src.rpm` but this fails:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:57 ago on Thu 19 May 2022 12:23:23 PM CDT.
Error: Will not install a source rpm package (htslib-1.9-5.el7.src).
```

How can I install `htslib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `htslib-tools` package which provides `bgzip` is available in [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/) for both RHEL 7 and 8 (you didn't specify the version of RHEL you are running) so just enable EPEL:

RHEL 8:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-$(arch)-rpms
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

RHEL 7:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

and use `yum install htslib-tools` to install it.

Comment: I should add that in between the first two commands for RHEL8, the CPG key should be imported: `rpm --import http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8`